# Invalid Firebase Database path.Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

```
did= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Patients").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("devID");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(String.valueOf(did)).child("BT").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String f_bt=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                bt.setText(f_bt);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

[image: My firebase realtime db's picture]

In this piece of code, I'm trying to fetch current use uid. And under UID, I'm fetching devID, which is "123456", and so using that devID i can use it as the path, as the sibling of UID and get all data of childs like "BT,DBP,HR,SBP". But I'm getting error as "Invalid Firebase Database path"

Comment: You can't just turn `did` into a string and expect it to query the database.  You have add a listener to get the first value, then add another listener to get the second value.

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't get You sir... Could you please explain me with the above piece of code?